# HTML Columns with Divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a bar on the left of the window, with a set width, with another div that fills the right side of the window. I've tried using "float:left;" on both, but this results in the "right" area to get stacked below the left bar.

[image: Correct]

This is correct, except I need the white area at the right to be filled by the other div.
With my current try, this is what happens:

[image: Problem]

How can I get the bottom div to fill up the white area to the right? The black gradient is a background: setting, and will scale properly.

Thanks!

Comment: How would you like to provide a little code too? Preferably on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out how to do this already... For anyone else needing to know how:

For the left bar, you need a set known width, in this replace %width% with your width...

CSS:

```
.leftBar{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    color:white;
    height: 100%;
    width: %width%;
}
.mainCenterContent{
padding-left:%width%;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="leftBar">
bleh
</div>
<div class="mainCenterContent">
    bleh
</div>
```

As you can see the padding essentially moves the div over enough to not intersect with the left bar. This is working properly for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to have a

```
clear:both;
```

after the two components.

see this: [Sidebar](http://jsfiddle.net/Vainglory07/G6uny/1/)

Comment: Your example renders the same way without clearing the floats, and so doesn't seem to help with the columns issue. Clearing floats is most useful if you have elements relatively positioned below the floated elements or if you need a container to accurately reflect the height of its floated contents: http://jsfiddle.net/HkEMc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method:

```
<style>
body, html {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
div#left_nav {
  position:relative;
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  background-color:#58A;
  height:100%;
}
div#page_content {
  position:static;
  background-color:#CDF;
  height:100%;
}
```

```
<body>
  <div id="left_nav">left menu</div>
  <div id="page_content">page content</div>
</body>
```

There are many different methods of making 2-column layouts.
Some are more complicated than others.
I find that, the more complicated my design becomes, the more robust my layout needs to be.
Search around and you will find one that is best for your needs.